# Setting up RaspAP

Tags: pi-2

I have just downloaded RaspAP onto my Pi 2 Model B. Upon rebooting, I am now able to see the "raspi-webgui" network on my mobile phone. However, when I enter the default password ChangeMe, it does not seem to connect. What seems to be the issue, and is there a possibility to change the password?

Comment: For people having issues with this, feel free to ask for help on the Github page - https://github.com/billz/raspap-webgui

Comment: Same issue here. I have confirmed the password is correct in hotapd.conf, yet I can't connect with that password

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following username and password?

```
username: admin
password: secret
```

Comment: Where should I enter this username and password? Also, now my Pi says "Connection to dhcpcd lost" when I hover over the wireless network selection.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, from ifconfig(on terminal) find the ip adress (for me it is 10.3.141.1) and type it on your browser (from raspi)
In the interface enter the default login :

```
username: admin
password: secret
```

then you can change settings and password from configuration tab